# error message when using Service Authentication Invalid grant

Tags: docusignapi

I am getting an error while attempting to trade code for access token. Stating invalid grant. Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Here is the code:

```
var integratorId = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx';
var secretKey = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx';

var basic = base64.encode(integratorId + ':' + secretKey);

console.log(basic);

var JWTheader = {"typ":"JWT", "alg":"RS256"};
var JWTbody = {
                "iss":"bfcb8406-4994-4715-8f6d-112f5670db2d",
                "sub":"832f391a-a3f7-4c29-b8f0-3226c06accd2",
                "aud": "account-d.docusign.com",
                "scope": "signature"

                };



var unSignedToken = base64.encode(JWTheader) + '.' +  base64.encode(JWTbody);
var cert = fs.readFileSync('/home/toplevelstaging/TopLevelAPI/routes/fs_node/RSAkey.pem');
var token = jwt.sign({unSignedToken, iat:Math.floor(Date.now()/100),exp:Math.floor(Date.now()/1000)+60}, cert, {algorithm:'RS256'});


var baseUrl = 'https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/3465212';


var oauth = 'https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token';


var tokenUrl = 'grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer&assertion='+token;




request({
    headers:{"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Authorization":"Basic "+basic},
    url:oauth,
    json: true, 
    method: "POST",
    data: tokenUrl,
    },function(err,response,body){
        console.log(response);
    }
);
```

Here is the error I am receiving:

```
 body: { error: 'invalid_grant' } }
```

Comment: integratorId  and SecretKey should be private and only you should have access to them. They should not be posted in a public forum like this.

Answer (score 1):

Which JWT library are you using?

The JWT library should take care of creating the JWT for you--you should not be dealing with the base64 encoding of the token parts.

From your example, it appears that you're hand rolling parts of the JWT, then using a library for the signing.

Look for a better library that handles everything for you. See my [blog post](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-using-the-oauth-jwt-flow/) and recipe for more tips.

Comment: I am using jsonwebtoken for node.js I undid the base64 encoding and still getting the same error.